# Generate random string from wxListBox in Python

Tags: python, arrays, random, wxpython

My code below allows the user to enter a customer name (string) into a wxTextCtrl field and then click a button to add the customer's name to a wxListBox.

```
if not self.addCustText.IsEmpty():
            mytext = self.addCustText.Value
            self.txtListBox.Append(str(mytext))
```

How can I randomly generate a single customer name from all the names the user enters into the wxListBox?

Answer (score 0):

`import random` and

```
 x = random.ranint(0, (size_of_xwListBox-1)
```

Then, just index your customer list at `x`.